# how to store meta data in animation keys?

Tags: animation, godot, gdscript

I have an animation track and I'm trying to store some associated meta data in keys

[image]

Now I *could* store it in the values of the keys like this:

```
track_get_key_value(track_idx,key_idx).set_meta("data","value")
```

but this only works for object type values like `texture` but not for other basic data types (like `Rect2`)
so is there any way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

#### why am I doing this?

I have some custom nodes with some custom properties & I don't want to animate them,
so I'm trying to store their values in the meta data of inbuilt properties of the nodes I extended from,
that way when I remove my custom nodes everything would still work

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest a different direction: You can have a node that manipulates the `AnimationPlayer`.

For reference, see how you would use an `AnimationTree`, it has a `NodePath` called `anim_player` that you set so it know what `AnimationPlayer` it would work with.

Same idea. Make a custom `Node` that exports a `NodePath` to an `AnimationPlayer`, then it can manipulate the `AnimationPlayer` and monitor its state.

In particular, it can set property `playback_process_mode` of the `AnimationPlayer` to `ANIMATION_PROCESS_MANUAL` and then advance it with `seek` and `advance` from `_process`. So that your custom `Node` is in control of the position of the `AnimationPlayer` and can do other things in sync with it.

Some examples of things you can do with this approach:

- Stop the animations at a particular time you want (no more using a timer to stop the animation early, which is not precise).
- Loop a section of the animation.
- Have a second hidden `AnimationPlayer` with extra animation data and play them both in sync.
- Compute the value for other properties based on the current state of the animation.
- Enforce preconditions to play animations.

*We are, of course, assuming that no other code using `seek` and `advance` on the `AnimationPlayer`.*

The rest of the code could interface with the `AnimationPlayer` as usual, or it could interface with your custom node.

---

I have a custom `Node` that does something similar to what I describe. It sets `playback_process_mode` to `ANIMATION_PROCESS_MANUAL`, however I still call `play` and `stop` normally. I can use `seek` to set the start time of the animation right after calling `play`...

The custom `Node` will read `current_animation` and `current_animation_position` to know where on the animation it is. And on `_process` it will do this:

```
    var current_time := _animation_player.current_animation_position
    next_time = current_time + delta
    _animation_player.advance(delta)
    _animation_player.seek(next_time, true)
```

I use both `advance` and `seek` as workaround for this issue: [`AnimationPlayer.advance()` doesn't advance audio #48982](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/48982).

---

Now given what you have described in other questions… I'm going to suggest that the custom `Node` could:

- Extend `AnimationPlayer` (so it does not need a `NodePath`, since the `AnimationPlayer` is itself).
- Create a second hidden `AnimationPlayer`.
- Store extra information in the `Animation`s of the hidden `AnimationPlayer`
- And play the hidden `AnimationPlayer` in sync with it self by using `seek` and `advance` while `playback_process_mode` is set to `ANIMATION_PROCESS_MANUAL`.